# How to access hard drive in OpenSuse 11.4 running on VMWare?

Tags: vmware, mount, opensuse-11.4

I am using OpenSuse 11.4 through VMWare. I also have OpenSuse 11.2 and I can access the hard drive by mounting it, i.e :

```
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/myDriveF
```

However, I'm not able to do this in OpenSuse 11.4. It's saying :

```
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems the problem is the result of some changes in the 2.3.36 kernel.

During build of the vmware-tools, the necessary vmhgfs module throws the following error message:

> /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/super.c:73:
>   error: unknown field ‘clear_inode’
>   specified in initializer

Root of the problem is that the `clear_inode()` function has been renamed `evict_indode()`.

So -- simply patch the source code of the corresponding part of the vmhgfs driverand rebuild the tools in 5 easy steps I nicked from here: http://vmware-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=21774

1. Go to `/usr/lib/vmware-tools/modules/source` and unpack `vmhgfs.tar`
2. `cd` into the new directory and open `'super.c'` in your favorite editor
3. Change the following:

   ```
   #ifndef VMW_USE_IGET_LOCKED
      .read_inode    = HgfsReadInode,
   #endif
      **.clear_inode   = HgfsClearInode,**
      .put_super     = HgfsPutSuper,
      .statfs        = HgfsStatfs,
   };
   ```

   To read:

   ```
   #ifndef VMW_USE_IGET_LOCKED
      .read_inode    = HgfsReadInode,
   #endif
      **.evict_inode   = HgfsClearInode,**
      .put_super     = HgfsPutSuper,
      .statfs        = HgfsStatfs,
   };
   ```
4. Save the file and repack everything into `vmhgfs.tar`
5. Run `vmware-config-tools.pl`